# Compare two strings in C# when getting them from Excel Interop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, excel-interop

I'm trying to compare two strings in C# as I pull them from Excel using the Interop interface.  My code is as follows:

```
public Boolean isSameEdge(Edge e)
    {
        Boolean result = false;
        String e1 = e.getNode1();
        String e2 = e.getNode2();
        int s1 = String.Compare(e1, Node1);
        int s2 = String.Compare(e2, Node2);

        if (s2 == 0 && s1 == 0)
            result = true;

        return result;
    }
```

I'm debugging the code and I see that e1 and Node1 are the EXACT same string, as they should be.  Yet String.Compare returns 1 for s1 and -1 for s2.  Help!

Comment: Obviously they aren't the exact same string. Can you convert them to an unambiguous format (e.g. bytes as hex) and post them?

Comment: Might be worth getting a byte array in the encoding of your choice by using one of the `System.Text.Encoding` classes. Try `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e1)` and a similar call for `e2` and compare the byte values. This will probably show you where each is different.

Comment: @Mark - How do I do that?  When viewing the values in the debugger in Visual Studio e1 = "we" and node1 = "we".  How do I convert these to hex?  Unsure how to do what Adam is asking either...

Comment: What exactly are "Node1" and "Node2" ? And what does `getNode1()` do exactly?

Comment: I guess you use Range.Value to access the values from Excel. As far as I see the return type of this function is object. Might be a good idea to check if this object can directly be converted to string, because in C# string is always a series of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty safe to assume that String.Compare() doesn't have a bug.  These strings probably only *look* the same.  Beware of unprintable characters like (char)0.  Diagnose with String.ToCharArray().